# How do I prevent a Matlab test with "assertWarning" from printing warning text to the console?

Tags: matlab, testing, tdd, warnings, suppress-warnings

I am trying to implement a basic testing framework in Matlab as my first attempt at Test-Driven-Development. One of the tests I am trying to create is intended to verify that my function throws a specific warning under certain input conditions. My code is passing the warning-related tests as intended, however there is a huge annoyance.

When running (and passing) tests involving the "assertWarning" or "verifyWarning" functions, the warnings that are supposed to be triggered are printed to the command window and visually disrupt the printout of my test suite. **Is there a way to prevent the (desired) warning from printing to the console only when being run in the tests, while still verifying that the warning is triggered?** A sample test function which causes this annoying warning printout is below.

```
function testAcceleratorMax(testCase)
% Validate that acceleration input is forced to be <=1 and throws warning
state = [0,0,0,0]; input = [2,0];
xd = getPointMass2D_dot(state,input);
assert(isequal(xd,[0,0,1,0]),'Acceleration not ceiled correctly');
verifyWarning(testCase,@(x) getPointMass2D_dot(state,input),...
    'MATLAB:CommandedAccelOutOfBounds');
end
```

Comment: Have you looked at [suppress warnings?](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/suppress-warnings.html)

Comment: @UnbearableLightness I have looked at it. The problem with "suppress warnings" is that it defeats the purpose of the test. I WANT the tested function to throw warnings when certain conditions are met. By suppressing the warning, the test function fails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it may not be the most elegant solution, I have found a much less intrusive method!

Step 1: Turn the specific warnings you are deliberately triggering to off in the test suite setup function. You could also do this and step 2 within each test function individually if needed. Even when the warning is turned off and won't print to the command window, you can access the suppressed warning using "lastwarn".

```
function setup(testCase)
warning('off','MATLAB:CommandedAccelOutOfBounds');
warning('off','MATLAB:CommandedSteerOutOfBounds');
end
```

Step 2: Turn the specific warnings back on in the test suite teardown function to reset matlab to the correct state after running the test suite.

```
function teardown(testCase)
warning('on','MATLAB:CommandedAccelOutOfBounds');
warning('on','MATLAB:CommandedSteerOutOfBounds');
end
```

Step 3: Instead of using the "verifyWarning" or "assertWarning" functions for your test, use "lastwarn" and "strcmp".

```
function testAcceleratorMax(testCase)
% Validate that acceleration input is forced to be <=1 and throws warning
state = [0,0,0,0]; input = [2,0];
xd = getPointMass2D_dot(state,input);
assert(isequal(xd,[0,0,1,0]),'Acceleration not ceiled correctly');
[~,warnID] = lastwarn; % Gets last warning, even though it was "off"
assert(strcmp(warnID,'MATLAB:CommandedAccelOutOfBounds'), 'Correct warning not thrown')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much of what your code does, but you can always do something like:

```
A = eye(2);
B = [3 6; 4 8];
evalc('C=B\A'); % the warning gets suppressed. It also gets outputted by this function, but it can also output other command window prints
lastwarn; %grab the last warning
```

But **CAREFUL!** `evalc` evaluates everything that gets inside. That includes commands that will destroy your computer like
`system('suda rm -rf/')`*

*typo on purpose.

Comment: Thanks for putting in the deliberate typo! I could imaging someone blindly using Ctrl-C Ctrl-V oh no Ctrl-Z otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method to decrease the annoyance of the warnings printing while running the test suite. However, this may cause some later issues. In the setup function for the test suite, you can set warnings to be terse and the backtrace to be off (and reset them to their default state in the teardown function).

```
function setup(testCase)
warning off verbose;
warning off backtrace;
end

function teardown(testCase)
warning on verbose;
warning on backtrace;
end
```

As you can see below, this cuts down on quite a bit of warning text printing to the console. However, if, during the TDD process, you wanted to actually use the backtrace of an unintended test failure, you would have to turn the warning backtrace on. I suppose you could turn the backtrace off and on within each function test manually, but it still doesn't seem like an optimal solution.

Sample command window output with verbose off, backtrace off:

```
> Running tests_getPointMass2D_dot  
> .....Warning: The acceleration commanded was set to the max accel allowed  
> .Warning: The acceleration commanded was set to the min accel allowed  
> .Warning: The steering commanded was set to the max steer allowed  
> .Warning: The steering commanded was set to the min steer allowed  
> .  
> Done tests_getPointMass2D_dot
> __________
> Totals:    9 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Incomplete.   
> 0.19797 seconds testing time.
```

Sample command window output with verbose on, backtrace on:

```
> Running tests_getPointMass2D_dot .....Warning: The acceleration
> commanded was set to the max accel allowed (Type "warning off
> MATLAB:CommandedAccelOutOfBounds" to suppress this warning.)
>  
> > In getPointMass2D_dot (line 43)   In tests_getPointMass2D_dot>testAcceleratorMax (line 55)   In
> matlab.unittest.FunctionTestCase/test (line 98)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodCore (line 995)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodsOnTestContent (line 936)  
> In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestMethod (line 1287)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTest (line 1244)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/repeatTest (line 586)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runSharedTestCase (line 548)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestClass (line 1170)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line
> 1037)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestClass (line
> 378)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.testrunprogress.ConciseProgressPlugin/runTestClass
> (line 68)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins
> (line 895)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestSuite (line 1102)  
> In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line
> 1037)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 229)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.FailureDiagnosticsPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 95)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite
> (line 229)   In
> matlab.unittest.internal.plugins.ListenerAdderPlugin/runTestSuite
> (line 29)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.DiagnosticsRecordingPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 165)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins
> (line 895)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/run (line 307)   In
> runtests (line 90)  .Warning: The acceleration commanded was set to
> the min accel allowed (Type "warning off
> MATLAB:CommandedAccelOutOfBounds" to suppress this warning.)
>  
> > In getPointMass2D_dot (line 47)   In tests_getPointMass2D_dot>testAcceleratorMin (line 64)   In
> matlab.unittest.FunctionTestCase/test (line 98)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodCore (line 995)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodsOnTestContent (line 936)  
> In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestMethod (line 1287)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTest (line 1244)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/repeatTest (line 586)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runSharedTestCase (line 548)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestClass (line 1170)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line
> 1037)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestClass (line
> 378)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.testrunprogress.ConciseProgressPlugin/runTestClass
> (line 68)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins
> (line 895)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestSuite (line 1102)  
> In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line
> 1037)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 229)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.FailureDiagnosticsPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 95)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite
> (line 229)   In
> matlab.unittest.internal.plugins.ListenerAdderPlugin/runTestSuite
> (line 29)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.DiagnosticsRecordingPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 165)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins
> (line 895)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/run (line 307)   In
> runtests (line 90)  .Warning: The steering commanded was set to the
> max steer allowed (Type "warning off MATLAB:CommandedSteerOutOfBounds"
> to suppress this warning.)
>  
> > In getPointMass2D_dot (line 54)   In tests_getPointMass2D_dot>testSteeringMax (line 73)   In
> matlab.unittest.FunctionTestCase/test (line 98)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodCore (line 995)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodsOnTestContent (line 936)  
> In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestMethod (line 1287)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTest (line 1244)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/repeatTest (line 586)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runSharedTestCase (line 548)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestClass (line 1170)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line
> 1037)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestClass (line
> 378)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.testrunprogress.ConciseProgressPlugin/runTestClass
> (line 68)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins
> (line 895)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestSuite (line 1102)  
> In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line
> 1037)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 229)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.FailureDiagnosticsPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 95)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite
> (line 229)   In
> matlab.unittest.internal.plugins.ListenerAdderPlugin/runTestSuite
> (line 29)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.DiagnosticsRecordingPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 165)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins
> (line 895)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/run (line 307)   In
> runtests (line 90)  .Warning: The steering commanded was set to the
> min steer allowed (Type "warning off MATLAB:CommandedSteerOutOfBounds"
> to suppress this warning.)
>  
> > In getPointMass2D_dot (line 58)   In tests_getPointMass2D_dot>testSteeringMin (line 82)   In
> matlab.unittest.FunctionTestCase/test (line 98)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodCore (line 995)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodsOnTestContent (line 936)  
> In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestMethod (line 1287)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTest (line 1244)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/repeatTest (line 586)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runSharedTestCase (line 548)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestClass (line 1170)   In
> matlab.unittest.TestRunner/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line
> 1037)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestClass (line
> 378)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.testrunprogress.ConciseProgressPlugin/runTestClass
> (line 68)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins
> (line 895)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/runTestSuite (line 1102)  
> In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_ (line
> 1037)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 229)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.FailureDiagnosticsPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 95)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/runTestSuite
> (line 229)   In
> matlab.unittest.internal.plugins.ListenerAdderPlugin/runTestSuite
> (line 29)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.DiagnosticsRecordingPlugin/runTestSuite (line
> 165)   In
> matlab.unittest.plugins.TestRunnerPlugin/invokeTestContentOperatorMethod_
> (line 658)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/evaluateMethodOnPlugins
> (line 895)   In matlab.unittest.TestRunner/run (line 307)   In
> runtests (line 90)  . Done tests_getPointMass2D_dot
> __________
> 
> 
> Totals:    9 Passed, 0 Failed, 0 Incomplete.  
>    0.20351 seconds testing time.
```